# Include static library into shared library using Gradle's Native Binary support

Tags: java-native-interface, gradle, static-libraries, android-gradle-plugin, dynamic-library

I have 2 projects:

- A static libray `libSL.a` built with the NDK r9 and `Android.mk`.
- An Android Studio project containing:

  - `WL.java` (a JNI wrapper around `libWL.so`).
  - `jniWL.h` and `jni/WL.c` (`libWL.so`'s source code), which require `libSL.a`.
  - `lib/libWL.so`.

How do I include `libSL.a` into `libWL.so` with [Gradle's Native Binary support](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html)?

Answer (score 0):

To include static library you need to add it at linking stage as parameter for linker. It should not matter if target is shared lib or executable. I used

```
ndk {
    ...
    ldLibs "/some/path/libs/libcurl.a", "z", "log", "android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "OpenSLES"
}
```

in my project. And also:

```
 stl "gnustl_static"
```

And that gave me native .so module.